# Maven Repositories - Nexus Alternative

Tags: amazon-web-services, java, maven

We are using BitBucket and Git for source control of a Java Spring Boot application that uses Maven as it build tool hosted on AWS.

We want to create a repository to store out dependencies. We did consider using a self managed Nexus repo, but would rather use a cloud based solutions (like AWS CodeArtifact).

Does anyone have any recommendations please?  Is AWS CodeArtifact a good solution?

Comment: AWS CodeArtifact - Get 2 GB of storage per month with the AWS Free Tier